# Date coming back wrong from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jscript

I have a date in my table that is in there as 2016-12-05 etc

When I use a select statement to get that value back however it comes back in a really odd way: Mon Dec 5 00:00:00 UTC 2016

How do I get this to come back in YYYY-MM-DD?

Edit:

Using JSCRIPT. Select command is

```
SELECT AccessDate from screens.signoff WHERE BadgeNo = '" + BadgeNo + "'"
```

BadgeNo being a variable defined above somewhere

Comment: maybe if you share some code... ;)

Comment: Show us how you query the table for this date column

Comment: What datatype is this column in your schema

Comment: This seems to be a formatting issue only, without any hint as to how you retrieve the data, it is impossible for us to tell what may have gone wrong.

Comment: SQL stores date information in the database usually as an offset from a particular point in time. Selecting the date out converts it to a string format for display - it depends where you are displaying this date but the general rule is, convert to a string at the last moment possible. We can't tell what your "last moment" is because the question doesn't include where or how you want to display the value...

Comment: In this case you probably want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date, mostly the second answer - using `moment.js` if possible will save you a load of headache. The date/time implementation in JavaScript and variations is generally poor.

Comment: which data base client you use. there should be option to change date time format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT()` function for this

In your case, it will be :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AccessDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as AccessDate from screens.signoff WHERE BadgeNo = '" + BadgeNo + "'"
```

refer this documentation
[MySQL DATE_FOMAT() reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Edit: I just missed a single quote in the answer

Comment: It should, SELECT DATE_FORMAT(AccessDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as AccessDate from screens.signoff WHERE BadgeNo = '" + BadgeNo + "'"

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

*for **MySQL***

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myValue, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

look for str_to_date : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

edit: *for **MSSQL***

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

why 126?  look there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: This is MySql as specified by the tags... pretty sure MS didn't work on this one :)

Comment: @Maharshi I disagree: `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GetDate(),126)' at line 1"`. This is MySql not MSSQL.

Comment: @Charleh I am talking about MSSQL, I agree with you about MySQL.
Pardon me, I missed to state it in previous comment.

Comment: @Charleh  I edited  for MySQL   :)  Maybe this can help?

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$Date_database= $row['date']; // your database code
$Date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date_database)); // change to right date format
```

Date Contains 2016-12-05 now

Comment: This assumes the OP is using PHP.... which isn't mentioned in the question or tags anywhere?

Comment: Assumptions are the number one reason for problems!